# Perl - script to automatically add username and password to the Linux system

Tags: linux, perl, centos, system-administration

Good day!
I just wanted help with one issue. I created students.txt list where it is like this in CentOS Linux command line:

```
said:123456
taha:456789
```

I created perl file where there is a script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
$filename = 'students.txt';
open(FILE, $filename);
while(<FILE>)
{
chomp;
($user, $passcode) = split(/:/, $_);
system "useradd $user  -m -p  $passcode";
}
close FILE;
print "Users are created successfully :) \n";
```

After running the perl file, it is adding the usernames but not passwords. Also I am new to Perl. Thank you in advance.

Comment: `useradd -p` expects passwords encrypted by `crypt`.

Comment: if I remove encryption  (-p), will it be working? Thank you

Comment: `-p` isn't the part asking for encryption. You must pass it encrypted.

Comment: The Passwd::Unix module may be of interest to you too

Answer (score 0):

### Simply include the chpasswd command.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

$filename = 'students.txt';
open(FILE, $filename) or die $!;
while($line = <FILE>) {
    chomp $line;
    ($user, $passcode) = split(/:/, $line);
    system "useradd $user -m";
}
close FILE;
system "chpasswd < students.txt";
print "Users are created successfully :) \n";
```